# Postponing employee start date

Tags: employer-relations, employment

If a person has been given a start date but 3 days prior to starting has been asked to postpone the start date by a day, are there any obligations by the employer to pay from the original start date?

Comment: How long are you asking them to stay unemployed for?

Comment: If it's only one day, it's probably more trouble than it's worth to pursue, even if they ARE obligated to pay.  Not only would it create a poor first impression, but the legal fees would likely exceed the pay you stand to recoup.  If it was something like a month delay, I'd say ask a lawyer, but just for one day, I'd just let it go.

Answer (score 2):

> If a person has been given a start date but 3 days prior to starting
>   has been asked to postpone the start date by a day, are there any
>   obligations by the employer to pay from the original start date?

It depends on local laws.

Where I live, there is no obligation for a company to pay you until you actually start working.

Comment: Interesting problem for an employee, what if they said a month?